# How to reduce the amount of Javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am just learning Javascript, and would like to make the code shorter.

The parts I would like to make shorter involve the blocks of code where `vertical_axis` is set to `2`, `3`, and `4`.

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var FChartValue = new Array();
        var FChartName = new Array();


        $("document").ready(function () {

            var horizontal_axis = 1; // Number of column for "Horizontal Axis" counted from "Title" column = 0
            var arrayList = $("td.ms-vb-title:contains('')");
            arrayList = arrayList.closest('tbody').find('tr');
            var arrayList_temp = null;
            $(arrayList).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(1).text() != "") {
                    if (arrayList_temp)
                        arrayList_temp = arrayList_temp.add($(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(horizontal_axis));
                    else
                        arrayList_temp = $(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(horizontal_axis);
                }
            });
            var Coords = new Array();
            var Coords1 = new Array();
            var Coords2 = new Array();
            var Labels = new Array();
            $.each(arrayList_temp, function (i, e) {
                Labels[i] = $(e).text();
            });

            var vertical_axis = 2; // Number of column for "Vertical Axis" counted from "Title" column = 0
            var arrayList1 = $("td.ms-vb-title:contains('')");
            arrayList1 = arrayList1.closest('tbody').find('tr');
            var arrayList1_temp = null;
            $(arrayList1).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(1).text() != "") {
                    if (arrayList1_temp)
                        arrayList1_temp = arrayList1_temp.add($(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(vertical_axis));
                    else
                        arrayList1_temp = $(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(vertical_axis);
                }
            });
            $.each(arrayList1_temp, function (i, e) {
                Coords[i] = $(e).text();
            });

            var vertical_axis1 = 3; // Number of column for "Vertical Axis" counted from "Title" column = 0
            var arrayList2 = $("td.ms-vb-title:contains('')");
            arrayList2 = arrayList2.closest('tbody').find('tr');
            var arrayList2_temp = null;
            $(arrayList2).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(1).text() != "") {
                    if (arrayList2_temp)
                        arrayList2_temp = arrayList2_temp.add($(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(vertical_axis1));
                    else
                        arrayList2_temp = $(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(vertical_axis1);
                }
            });
            $.each(arrayList2_temp, function (i, e) {
                Coords1[i] = $(e).text();
            });

            var vertical_axis2 = 4; // Number of column for "Vertical Axis" counted from "Title" column = 0
            var arrayList3 = $("td.ms-vb-title:contains('')");
            arrayList3 = arrayList3.closest('tbody').find('tr');
            var arrayList3_temp = null;
            $(arrayList3).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(1).text() != "") {
                    if (arrayList3_temp)
                        arrayList3_temp = arrayList3_temp.add($(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(vertical_axis2));
                    else
                        arrayList3_temp = $(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(vertical_axis2);
                }
            });
            $.each(arrayList3_temp, function (i, e) {
                Coords2[i] = $(e).text();
            });

            FChartValue = Coords;
            FChartValue1 = Coords1;
            FChartValue2 = Coords2;
            FChartName = Labels;
        });

        //Graph Rendering
        google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            data.addColumn('string', 'Number');
            data.addColumn('number', 'P1');
            data.addColumn('number', 'P2');
            data.addColumn('number', 'P3');

            data.addRows(FChartValue.length);

            for (i = 0; i < FChartValue.length; i++) {
                data.setValue(i, 0, FChartName[i]);
                data.setValue(i, 1, parseInt(FChartValue[i]));
                data.setValue(i, 2, parseInt(FChartValue1[i]));
                data.setValue(i, 3, parseInt(FChartValue2[i]));
            }

            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, {
                title: 'Report for Electric Energy Consumption',
                width: 1000, height: 400, is3D: false,
                hAxis: { title: "Year" },
                vAxis: { title: "kW" }
            }
            );
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Best of luck! If there's any way we can help, feel free to ask a question and tell us where you're stuck.

Comment: **@DavidThomas**: I am worrying about the `data.setValue(i, 1, parseInt(FChartValue[i]));` How can I use the loop in this case with `i` that it contains another loop such as `j`?

Comment: In a glance the code seems to repeat itself.  Have you tried writing a named function to contain the repeated code?

Comment: **@Paul**: I am beginner of Javascript. Hence, it is quite difficult to me to write a function that contain all of the code. I would just like to make it short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see code that has the same pattern repeated over and over, the pattern can be made into a new function. The changeable parts are the parameters.

It seems the only thing that changes are the names of temporary variables, which are only used to gather values into `Coords123...` and the `vertical_axis` value.

So it looks like we would need vertical_axis as a parameter.  A coords array needs to be the return value.  The body of the function can be taken from one of the duplicates, and simply cleaned up a bit.

The function should be named to be useful when you, or someone else, sees it again later.

The repeated code has the main effect of filling in values for a Coords array.  So we could name the function `getCoords`.

Also note there is a style in Javascript that many programmers use, where a name with multiple words like get coords has the first letter lower case and the first letter of each subsequent word Capitalized so that when the words run together you can visually separate them.  getCoords is easier to read than getcoords

```
function getCoords(vertical_axis){
            var Coords=[]; // Coords will be used to store the result to be returned
            var arrayList1 = $("td.ms-vb-title:contains('')");
            arrayList1 = arrayList1.closest('tbody').find('tr');
            var arrayList1_temp = null;
            $(arrayList1).each(function () {
                if ($(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(1).text() != "") {
                    if (arrayList1_temp)
                        arrayList1_temp = arrayList1_temp.add($(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(vertical_axis));
                    else
                        arrayList1_temp = $(this).find('td.ms-vb2').eq(vertical_axis);
                }
            });
            $.each(arrayList1_temp, function (i, e) {
                Coords[i] = $(e).text();
            });
            return Coords;
}
```

Then the 3 copies of this code pattern can be reduced to 3 uses of this function as follows:

```
Coords = getCoords(2);
Coords1 = getCoords(3);
Coords2 = getCoords(4);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Honestly, I just started with Javascript few days ago, I was attempting to learn both Javascript and jQuery. It makes me crazy sometimes... Anyway thank you again.